# How to slide a GoogleMap correctly using ActionbarSherlock, jeremyfeinstein slidingmenu?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-maps-v2, slidingmenu

I have a problem sliding the map using ActionbarSherlock and Jeremyfeinstein slidingmenu. When I try to move on the map to the left (anywhere on the map) just move the Jeremyfeinstein SlidingMenu, but I just need to move the map.
Please see next image:
[image]

I need something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I found the solution, I had this:

```
getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
```

And I changed it:

```
getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
```